# Validate Thrift Enums with constant values

Tags: thrift

I have a Thrift file that specifies an enum as follows:

```
enum MyEnumStuff {
  ABC = 7,
  ...,
  XYZ = 9,
  ...,
  // Many, many, many other values...
}
```

Is there a way to add validations to guarantee that the numbers on the right side (i.e. 7, 9, etc...) are all unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [thriftlint](https://github.com/greeflas/awesome-thrift#tools) tool for validating your thrift definition files.

This tool provide you validator for [enums](https://github.com/UrbanCompass/thriftlint/blob/master/checks/enums.go) that you can use for checking index sequence.